Is it possible to directly encrypt a drive using any card in a smart card reader (even credit card, perhaps?)
As I understand it, a credit card chip or smart card works by sending challenges to the tiny computer on the card, at which point it completes the challenge and replies back with the data. Is it possible to use this to directly encrypt/decrypt data? Conventionally, you just use the card to store a key that is then transferred to the computer, but I think it would be fun to do all decryption/encryption on the tiny computer inside the card so that the host computer never sees the encryption key at all. The problem that I see is that the card itself may only be able to encrypt data which is then verified by the server of the credit card company, and would therefore be unable to decrypt data itself.
If it is possible to send both encryption and decryption challenges to the card and get a response, it should be simple to write a program that uses the card to encrypt a folder or a drive (though I imagine it would be very slow)
Tldr (or, to clarify): Is it possible to directly send challenges to a credit card or smart card in a smart card reader on linux and get the results back?

Re the "very slow": that's true – what's usually done is that you generate a random single-use symmetric key to be used for the actual encryption and you protect that random key with the asymmetric crypto functionality on the card. (This is also how sending an encrypted mail to two people doesn't double its size, because only the symmetric key is encrypted twice.)

Are you familiar with public key cryptography? Basically with a clever bit of math, you'll get a pair of keys, not just one. Either key of the pair can be used to encrypt data, and then only the other key of the pair will decrypt it.
Credit cards and many other smart cards are based on public key cryptography. Basically, if you used your credit card to encrypt some data with the key embedded in the card, you could not decrypt it yourself; only your bank or credit card company would have the corresponding key to decrypt it, and only your bank/credit card company would have the necessary key to send something you could decrypt with the key in the card. This makes it hard to use credit cards and the like for private encryption.
But nothing prevents you from buying uninitialized cards of your own, and initializing them with keys you control. Before you go buy some, though, you should have a more detailed understanding of what the smart cards can do and exactly how you're going to accomplish what you're planning to do. If you want help in that, you'll have to provide a more detailed explanation of exactly what you wish to achieve.
For example:

does the encrypted drive need to be bootable?
does it need to be indistinguishable from a drive wiped by overwriting it with random data, or is it allowed/required to be detectable as containing encrypted data?
is the purpose of the card to act as a sort of "dead man's handle", i.e. "remove the card to quickly make the data inaccessible"?

